# What is $debian_chroot in .bashrc?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, debian

What is the `debian_chroot` variable in my `.bashrc` file? and what is it doing here?

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
```

Comment: not much about it in the way of google, but you might like to look at http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=55243

Comment: It's ugly and unfriendly code that you will rarely ever use in your otherwise simple and elegant PS1 prompt. It seems that there would be a better way to do this (perhaps an `if $debian_chroot; then ... else` block).

Comment: The `PS1` I posted is default (K)Ubuntu prompt

Comment: See also [_AskUbuntu: What does “${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}” do in my terminal prompt?_](http://askubuntu.com/a/372862/23496)

Answer (score 45):

[Chroot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot) is a unix feature that lets you restrict a process to a subtree of the filesystem. One traditional use is FTP servers that chroot to a subset of the filesystem containing only a few utilities and configuration files, plus the files to serve; that way, even if an intruder manages to exploit a bug in the server, they won't be able to access files outside the chroot. Another common use is when you're installing or repairing a unix system and you boot from a different system (such as a live CD): once a basic system is available, you can chroot into it and do more work.

The prompt setting includes the content of `$debian_chroot` in the prompt, inside parentheses, unless it is empty. This variable is initialized in `/etc/bash.bashrc` to the contents of the file `/etc/debian_chroot`. Thus, if you follow the convention to include a name for your chroots at the location `/path/to/chroot/etc/debian_chroot`, your prompt will contain an indication of which chroot you're in. A program that follows this convention is [schroot](http://packages.debian.org/schroot), a tool for building and using chroots conveniently (I think the original intent was to facilitate having a stable Debian in a chroot inside an unstable or testing Debian, but the program has evolved quite a bit beyond that).