# $PS1 on Ubuntu VM does not match actual prompt

Tags: bash, prompt

I am running an Ubuntu VM out of `Virtual Box` and `Vagrant`:

```
vagrant@lucid64:~$ uname -a
Linux lucid64 2.6.32-38-server #83-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 4 11:26:59 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

My $PS1 variable doesn't actually match the prompt and is far more complex:

```
vagrant@lucid64:~$ echo $PS1
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$
```

I am looking for an explanation of the relationship between the $PS1 and my prompt, which is `$USER@$HOST:$PWD\$`, as can be seen above.

E.g., on my regular laptop, which hosts this VM and is a Mac, it is clean and simple as follows:

```
~@12:10:20>echo $PS1
\w@\t>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default `$PS1` in Ubuntu consists of three parts:

- `\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]`

  This is an escape sequence which will set the terminal title text to `$USER@$HOST: $PWD`.

  `\[` and `\]` indicate  the beginning and end of a sequence of non-printing characters.

  `\e` is an ASCII escape character.

  `]0;` is the specific escape sequence to [set the terminal icon and title](http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-mini/Xterm-Title.html#ss3.1) in `xterm` compatible terminals

  `\u` expands to the username of the current user.

  `@` is a literal @.

  `\h` expands to the hostname.

  `:` is a literal colon character.

  `\w` expands to the current working directory.

  `\a` is an ASCII bell character.
- `${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}`

  If you're in a chroot environment, this will expand to the name of the chroot in parentheses.

  [`${var:+OTHER}`](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/refcards.html#AEN22568) evaluates to `$OTHER` if `var` is set, otherwise as null string. `$debian_chroot` is a variable initalized in `/etc/bash.bashrc` to the contents of the file `/etc/debian_chroot`. Thus if your chroot environment includes this file, the prompt will include the contents of that file as an indication for which chroot the shell currently operates in.
- `\u@\h:\w\$`

  This is the actual prompt you typically see.

  `\u`, `@`, `\h`, `:`, `\w` are as above.

  `\$` expands to a number sign # if the effective uid is zero (i.e. user is root), otherwise it expands to a dollar sign $.

**Resources**

- [Bash prompt escape sequences](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/bash-prompt-escape-sequences.html)
- [Prompt magic](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-tip-prompt/)
- [How to change the title of and xterm](http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-mini/Xterm-Title.html)

Answer (score 3):

It's probably easiest to break this down!

In this first section:

```
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]
```

The first part of this (the `\[\e]0;` bit) contains terminal control characters (often used for colours in the bash prompt and updating window titles, among other things - I'll explain more further down.)

The second part (the `\u@\h:`) will give you the `user@host` part of the prompt, while the `\w` will echo the path of the current working directory. The `\a` is an [ASCII bell character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character).

[A quick search](http://www.arwin.net/tech/bash.php) revealed that, essentially, that part of your $PS1 is to tell `bash` to update the title of the terminal window to the same value as your prompt [like this](http://scottlab.ucsc.edu/xtal/tabs_iterm_closeup.png). (I know the shell pictured is `zsh`, but the same principle applies.) Essentially, that entire first 'phrase' is to update the current window title.

---

```
${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}
```

The part above simply means that "if the variable `$debian_chroot` is defined (i.e. not null), then include that string in the prompt". I'm fairly sure that the variable `$debian_chroot` only ever carries a value when the system's being chrooted into. [More info here.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3171/what-is-debian-chroot-in-bashrc)

---

```
\u@\h:\w\$
```

This last section creates the standard `user@host: ~/$` prompt.

HTH

Edit: whoops, seems like somebody beat me to it.