# Disallowing window renaming in tmux

Tags: tmux, window-title

I'm using `tmux` in OpenBSD (`tmux` in the base system of OpenBSD 6.1-beta), and I do some development on Linux hosts.

Whenever I log into a Linux host, it renames the current `tmux` window.  This is what's displayed in the lower right-hand corner of my `tmux` window:

```
"root@pelleplutt: /hom" 10:51 17-Mar-17
```

Pressing <kbd>prefix</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> shows the full window name as

```
(0)  0: ksh93* "root@pelleplutt: /home/ubuntu"
```

(this is after having logged into an lxc container I'm currently playing around with).

This is the name of the window even after having logged out of the Linux host, and it's a bit annoying that it sticks.

I'd like it to either (automatically) change back to whatever it was set to before logging into the Linux host, or to never change at all.

I've tried to disallow window renaming through using

```
set-window-option -g allow-rename off
set-window-option -g automatic-rename off
```

in my `.tmux.conf` file, but that doesn't seem to prevent whatever it is that sets the window name from doing so.

Any ideas how I may properly disallow window renaming in `tmux`?

---

**Additional info:**

The OpenBSD `tmux` doesn't tell the version:

```
$ command -v tmux
/usr/bin/tmux

$ tmux -V
tmux: unknown option -- V
usage: tmux [-2Cluv] [-c shell-command] [-f file] [-L socket-name]
            [-S socket-path] [command [flags]]
```

The `PS1` variable on the Linux host (Ubuntu 16.04 in an lxc container) is set to

```
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$
```

The `allow-rename` portion of the `tmux` manual:

```
allow-rename [on | off]
    Allow programs to change the window name using a terminal
    escape sequence (\ek...\e\\).  The default is on.
```

Doing `printf "\ektest\e\\"` sets the text which is displayed at the bottom *left* to `test` if `allow-rename` is `on`, but not if it's set to `off`.

Comment: @JigglyNaga No, it's `.tmux.conf`, sorry.

Comment: Odd, turning `allow-rename` off works for me. I've tried with tmux 1.8 and 2.1, using `echo -e '\033ktest\003\\'`.  Does it have any effect if you set the option from the tmux command prompt?

Comment: @JigglyNaga No, it doesn't.  Unfortunately I don't know what version `tmux` the one in the OpenBSD base system is based upon, but the manual mentions both settings. Your `echo` command seems to freeze the pane, and I have to kill it manually.

Comment: `tmux -V` should tell you the version.  I got that `echo` escape sequence from the `allow-rename` part of the `tmux` manpage.  The remote machine presumably sets the title using the `PS1` variable -- can you show what that's set to?

Comment: The `\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]` in your `$PS1`is an [escape sequence that sets the window title to `$USER@$HOST: $PWD`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/86924/43779). Would removing that from the `$PS1` in your `tmux` session be an option?

Comment: It doesn't freeze the pane.  JigglyNaga mis-typed the sequence.  All that you actually needed to do is `printf` the _correct_ termination sequence (which is `ST`, U+009C, 7-bit encodable as `ESC` \\).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [a thread in the tmux-users list asking about this](https://www.mail-archive.com/tmux-users@googlegroups.com/msg00005.html):

> allow-rename affects the window name not the title.

In your output from <kbd>Prefix</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>:

```
(0)  0: ksh93* "root@pelleplutt: /home/ubuntu"
```

The `"ksh93"` part is what `tmux` considers the **window name**.  It can be set by the escape sequence `\033k...\033\\`, and protected by the `allow-rename` option.

The `"root@pelleplutt: ..."` part is the **title**.  It's set by the escape sequence `\033[2;...\033\\`, and `tmux` doesn't have an option to protect that.

To prevent the remote system from changing the title, you could remove that sequence from the `PS1` variable:

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
```

Comment: Can't prevent it from setting the title, huh? That's unfortunate. I can change the value of `PS1`, but this container will be recreated from a standard image every once in a while, so it would have been better to simply disallow it from setting the title... However, now that I know what this text string is, I can reset it in my OpenBSD shell's `PS1` at least...

Comment: how to achieve the same on non-debian distros like arch Linux?

Comment: @AkhilJ The same: remove those escape sequences from the environment variable.

Comment: @JigglyNaga It's working but 2nd and 3rd panes are showing same old title. screenshot link:   [link](https://i.imgur.com/egljCFf.png)     Thank you.

Comment: @AkhilJ Please create a new question, including all necessary information to reproduce the problem, and what you've tried so far.

Comment: @JigglyNaga Question link:  [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/537882/weird-behaviour-in-xpanes-tmux-windows-title-naming)      Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

it's changed option name. so type 'man tmux' and need to check command.

```
$ tmux -V
tmux 3.1b

$ man tmux

 ...
 ...

 automatic-rename [on | off]
         Control automatic window renaming.  When this setting is enabled, tmux will rename the window automatically
         using the format specified by automatic-rename-format.  This flag is automatically disabled for an individual
         window when a name is specified at creation with new-window or new-session, or later with rename-window, or
         with a terminal escape sequence.  It may be switched off globally with:

               set-option -wg automatic-rename off
```