# weird behaviour in xpanes-tmux windows title naming

Tags: bash, terminal, tmux

my .tmux.conf.:

```
set -g mouse on
#set -g mouse-select-pane on
bind-key a set-window-option synchronize-panes\; display-message "synchronize-panes is now #{?pane_synchronized,on,off}"
set-window-option -g aggressive-resize
set -g pane-border-format "#P: #{pane_current_command}"
#tmux set -g pane-border-status top

set-window-option -g allow-rename off
set-window-option -g automatic-rename off
```

echo $PS1

```
PS1="\u@\h:\W\\$ "
```

Versions:

```
akhil@phoenix:~$ xpanes -V
xpanes 4.1.1
akhil@phoenix:~$ tmux -V
tmux 2.9a
```

screenshot:

```
xpanes -t -c "ping {}" 192.168.0.{1..9}
```

[image]

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/352066/disallowing-window-renaming-in-tmux

Comment: @JigglyNaga Yeah. But why only those two windows are showing a different title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it.

There is a `.bashrc` file in `/etc/bash.bashrc`

It is overriding with following

```
case ${TERM} in
  xterm*|rxvt*|Eterm|aterm|kterm|gnome*)
    PROMPT_COMMAND=${PROMPT_COMMAND:+$PROMPT_COMMAND; }'printf "\033]0;%s@%s:%s\007" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/\~}"'

    ;;
  screen*)
    PROMPT_COMMAND=${PROMPT_COMMAND:+$PROMPT_COMMAND; }'printf "\033_%s@%s:%s\033\\" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/\~}"'
    ;;
esac
```

I removed those lines and it's working fine.

> Still a mystery. Don't know why only two windows are affected.