# explanation of PS1 in bashrc

Tags: bashrc

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
```

I tried experimenting with this line a lot and was able to get a few characters, but I still don't get the complete meaning of the line. Can anyone please provide a detailed explanation of the line?

I got what I could from [this](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/bash-shell-ps1-10-examples-to-make-your-linux-prompt-like-angelina-jolie/) resource

Comment: Experiment with http://bashrcgenerator.com/ and http://ezprompt.net/ to get a feel for what that strange thing really means :)

Comment: K sure I will check it out. Thanks :)

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3171/117549

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}` -- checks if the variable `debian_chroot` is set, and expands to its value in parenthesis if it is. Debian's `bashrc` sets the variable earlier, I never use it so, I don't remember how its set. `${var:+word}` is a standard [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).
- `\[ .. \]` -- marker for non-printing characters, namely the color codes here. Bash needs these to calculate the length of the prompt so that the UI works properly
- `\033[01;32m` -- (that's ESC, backslash, etc.) terminal control code to set the output color (check any source on that for the meaning of the numbers)
- `\u@\h` -- username, literal `@`, hostname
- `\w` -- current working directory
- `\$` -- a dollar sign, unless you're root, in which case a hash sign `#`
- Note that there's a trailing space before the ending quote. Without it, the cursor would right against the dollar sign, which looks ugly.

See [Bash's manual for a reference on the backslash-codes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Controlling-the-Prompt.html) it interprets in prompts.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, your answer did help a lot :)