# Colored bash prompt and tab title

Tags: bash, colors, prompt, tabs

I cannot seem to get both a colored terminal prompt and the tab title to change at the same time.

```
function tab_title() {
    local tab_replace="${USER}@${HOSTNAME}"
    local tab_orig="$PS1"
    local tab_new="\e]2;${tab_replace}\a"
    echo "${tab_orig}${tab_new}"
}

function colour_prompt() {
    local c_off="\[\033[0m\]" # Colour off
    local c_red="\[\033[1;31m\]" # Colour red
    echo "${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}${c_red}\u@\h${c_off}/"
}

PS1="${tab_title}${color_prompt}"
```

I never managed to get the alternative tab title working

```
echo -en "\033]0;New terminal title\a"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Also, what are the `$debian_chroot` variables for?

Comment: as far as I can see, you never run `colour_prompt`?

Comment: [what is debian_chroot for](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3171/117549)

Comment: @ilkkachu good catch, updated